# Java: How to create a RSA Public Key from the String

Tags: java, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I have the byte array of the RSA Public Key. I found on the internet that I can create a real PublicKey object of it by using this code:

```
PublicKey publicKey = 
    KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
```

But every time I run this code, I'm getting another result for the encrypted data using that key. I'm sure the data I want to encrypt is always the same, so does the byte array representing the key.

Is this normal?

Here is my code always producing another output:

```
byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(rsa_1024_public_key);
      // rsa_1024_public key is a constant String

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

PublicKey publicKey =
   KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));

c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

return c.doFinal(password.getBytes());
```

This is probably a part of the asymmetric encryption algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: RSA is non-determinstic.

Comment: @SLaks: Do you want to post it as an answer? It's correct :D I'll give 35 rep points.

Comment: Actually, 15; I hit the rep limit long ago. :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488401/deterministic-rsa-encryption-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RSA is non-determinstic.

You can make it deterministic by selecting a non-random padding mode; however, that will not be secure.

Comment: Don't bother; I generally hit the rep limit every weekday.