# Decrypted string not the same as pre encrypted string

Tags: java, file, encryption, rsa

I have the following pieces of code:

**Globals**

```
public static PublicKey pubKey;
public static PrivateKey privKey;
public static Cipher cip;
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Generate the keys

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    Key publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    Key privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    cip = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");

    // Store Public Key.

    X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
            publicKey.getEncoded());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("public.key");
    fos.write(x509EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
    fos.close();

    // Store Private Key.
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            privateKey.getEncoded());
    fos = new FileOutputStream("private.key");
    fos.write(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
    fos.close();

    //Get the public and private keys out of their files
    getPubAndPrivateKey();

    //Check if the keys gotten out of the files are the same as the generated files (this returns truetrue)
    System.out.print(publicKey.equals(pubKey));
    System.out.print(privateKey.equals(privKey));


    byte[] text = "This is my super secret secret".getBytes();
    encryptToFile("encrypted.txt", text );
    decryptToFile("encrypted.txt", "decrypted.txt");

}
```

**Getting the keys from the files**

```
private static void getPubAndPrivateKey() throws IOException, Exception {
    // Read Public Key.
    File filePublicKey = new File("public.key");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("public.key");
    byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) filePublicKey.length()];
    fis.read(encodedPublicKey);
    fis.close();

    // Read Private Key.
    File filePrivateKey = new File("private.key");
    fis = new FileInputStream("private.key");
    byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) filePrivateKey.length()];
    fis.read(encodedPrivateKey);
    fis.close();

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
            encodedPublicKey);
    pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            encodedPrivateKey);
    privKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

}
```

**Encrypting**

```
    public static void encryptToFile(String fileName, byte[] data)
        throws IOException {

    try {
        cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        byte[] cipherData = cip.doFinal(data);
        String encryptedData = cipherData.toString();
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        out.write(encryptedData);
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
    }

}
```

**Decrypting**

```
private static void decryptToFile(String string, String string2)
        throws Exception {

    try {
        File encryptedFile = new File("encrypted.txt");

        byte[] encrypted = getContents(encryptedFile).getBytes();

        cip = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cip.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        byte[] cipherData = cip.doFinal(encrypted);

        String decryptedData = cipherData.toString();
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "decrypted.txt"));
        out.write(decryptedData);
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**Things I already checked**

- The data used in the decryption is the same as in the encrypted file
- The generated keys are the same as the ones gotten from the file
- The encryption and decryption both don't give errors

**Results**
Original string:
My super secret secret
The encryption results in:
[B@1747b17
The decryption results in:
[B@91a4fb

Comment: Take a look at [this][1] - maybe some of the tips can help you out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714327/rsa-badpaddingexception-data-must-start-with-zero

Comment: @zaske I changed it to "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" and the en/decryption work without errors. But 2 questions why does it work with "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" and not with "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" (I'm padding it both the same right?) And why does the decryption not work propperly?

Comment: Beginner Java errors are present here. In particular, the `(byte []).toString()` method does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @GregS that said, I would not mind if the byte[].toString() would be defined and would return a hexadecimal String. That object reference is bloody useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print out a byte array via `toString()` method you are getting a value that is totally independent of the content.

Therefore the values [B@1747b17 [B@91a4fb are just garbage that does not tell you anything.

If you want to print the content of a byte array convert it to Base64 or hex-string.

```
System.out.println(new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(myByteArray));
```

A hex string can be generated by using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex from [Apache Commons Codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/).

Comment: You beat me to that answer, it's wrong to assume that toString() is going to give a meaningful result in every case.  What this result says to me is that the original string is the one at location 1747b17 and the decrypted one is located at 91a4fb; in other words the original and decrypted string are not the same string (they are at different locations).  This may not be the correct way to interpret those strings but it works for me.  "same" is does not mean "equal". If I create two stings "a" and "a", they are not the same string because they are different instances but they are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It has been 4 years since I have programmed Java. Beginners mistake my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above answer.
I would like to add that in your case, you can simply use FileOutputStream, write the bytes to a file -
For example:

```
public static void encryptToFile(String fileName, byte[] data)
        throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        byte[] cipherData = cip.doFinal(data);
        out  = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        out.write(cipherData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
    } finally {
       if (fos != null) {
           try {
              fos.close();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
           }
       }
    }

}
```